# how to import a local js package instead of a network package

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, grandstack

I want to customize the default apollo-server that is included in  [grand-stack-starter](https://github.com/grand-stack/grand-stack-starter/tree/master/api)

to do this, I cloned [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server)
and replaced it (in grand-stack-starter)

`import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";`

for
`import { ApolloServer } from "C:/Users/a1ole/Documents/GitHub/apollo-server/packages/apollo-server-express/";`

but console return Error: "Cannot find module..."

Comment: because the file is not there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use an absolute path.
If you ever move the directory it will not work anymore. Also this will not work for anyone else, other than you.

Instead copy your apollo-server-express into your node_modules folder in your project, and import it like you would with any other module.